# I'm facing this problem in dart, is there a solution?

Tags: dart

```
main.dart:7:25: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
 var age=1021-num.parse(birth_years);
                        ^
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because `String?` is nullable and `String` is not. In other words, it expects a `String`, but you are providing something that might be a `String` or it might be `null`. Either provide a non-nullable String, or force the value with the `!` operator.

Keep in mind, forcing with `!` will throw an error if the value is null.

`myFunction(nullableString!);`

Comment: How do I write the code? Does his age count only when he enters the year he was born?

Comment: @mohammed the last line of the answer is how you would pass a String? as a String. I can't tell you how your code works other than that.